# Is there a way to call 2 microservices with Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

i have a question in using Spring Cloud Gateway. We can make "composite" calls with the help of Spring Cloud Gateway somehow?

I have a MicroService A and one MicroService B. My A needs some data from B to return when someone call ....ServiceA:port/serviceASomeEndpoint/both/{id}

It works oke when it's just using MicroServices port, i can fetch data from both services and return that data to the user, but when i use my Gateway MicroService with that port, it works partially, i can make "single" calls on just a Service with that port, but when i'm using in the combination with RestTemplate and trying ServiceGateway:port/serviceASomeEndpoint/both/{id} it doesn't work, and i don't know it's oke to behave like that...

What can i do to fetch both data from both microservices with Gateway help?

-Also, my RestTemplate it works only with ServiceB-host-and-port, i tried with the name registered in Eureka and nop, tried with the MyLocalHost + Gateway Port and nop, i didn't try in the Docker Compose way yet...

```
Masina masina = rest.getForObject("http://localhost:ServiceBPort(2000 for example)/masina/" + marca, Masina.class); - works if only we call with Service A port

Masina masina = rest.getForObject("http://localhost:GatewayPort(4000 for example)/masina/" + marca, Masina.class); - not working
```

Any ideas how to fetch and receive data from two services at once using Spring Cloud Gateway port?

Comment: Asking two slightly related questions make it difficult to answer. There's no composite call that joins responses. We have an open issue for an enhancement, but it's likely not to happen soon. It's going to be easier to forward a route to a local controller and manually combine calls.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer! And thanks for the tip, it's help a lot! Have a good day!